# Best way to access react-table instance from child to parent component [need your opinions]

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Currently I'm doing this:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useTable } from "react-table";

const Table = ({ onInit }) => {
  const table = useTable({ data: [...], columns: [...] });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    onInit(table);
  }, []);

  return <table>...</table>
};

const TableParent = () => {
  const [table, setTable] = React.useState();

  return <div>
    <Table onInit={table => setTable(table)} />
    <div>
      {/* Used table instance here */}
    </div>
  </div>
};
```

but not sure if this is fine or it is a bad pattern.
I'm a React beginner.
Please, I want to hear your opinions.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this, and it works well

Let's assume:
Parent component is App and
Child component is Table

From Parent component: You can pass a callback to table component

In table component: You call the same callback passing `instance` as a parameter using `hooks.useInstance` plugin point

I made it easy for you, **Check the console log**:

https://codesandbox.io/s/get-react-table-instance-in-parent-component-rx66s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I tried this, I was able to fetch the instance but whenever onChange occurs in the child component (Table) it refreshes again, what I'm trying to achieve is assign the pageSize to a state in the parent component, I hope you got my point and if you can reply to me thanks.

Comment: Okay, this is not expected, I might need more details of your code. Also check this FAQ here, as your table component resets or refreshes:
https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/188a392909bd9e5aa55e30daa235b4053c507c3b/docs/src/pages/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-stop-my-table-state-from-automatically-resetting-when-my-data-changes